Show $\exists f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f'(z) = \cos(z^{-1}) \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.
For $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ I have that:
\begin{align*}
\cos(z^{-1}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(\frac{1}{z})^{2k}}{(2k)!}
\end{align*}
I know from the ratio test that the radius of convergence $R = \infty$.
I know $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\cos(z^{-1})}$ is bounded between $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{-1}$ and $\enclose{horizontalstrike}{1}$.
I am not sure how best to proceed in my proof in order to produce a holomorphic function $f(z)$ such that this power series is it's derivative for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

$\cos(z^{-1})$ is  not bounded between $-1$ and $1$. Just integrate the series term by term to find $f(z)$.

You can integrate directly after $z=\frac 1x$

Set $f(z):=g(1/z)+z$, where $g(u):=\int_0^u\frac{1-\cos v}{v^2}\,dv$.

Anne Bauval : this is correct, can you elaborate on how you arrived at this function?

I followed Claude's suggestion but modified the integrand to remove its pole.
